# Django additional arguments to per view cache

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

In the excellent Django [cache framework documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/) it mentions the possibility of adding additional arguments to template fragment caching:

> Sometimes you might want to cache multiple copies of a fragment
>   depending on some dynamic data that appears inside the fragment. For
>   example, you might want a separate cached copy of the sidebar used in
>   the previous example for every user of your site. Do this by passing
>   additional arguments to the `{% cache %}` template tag to uniquely
>   identify the cache fragment:
>
> `{% load cache %} {% cache 500 sidebar request.user.username %}
>       .. sidebar for logged in user .. {% endcache %}`
>
> It’s perfectly fine to specify more than one argument to identify the fragment.
>   Simply pass as many arguments to `{% cache %}` as you need.

However it doesn't seem to mention anything about doing something similar when the per-view cache. It mentions the possible to use `@vary_on_headers` and `@vary_on_cookie`, but that is not quite the same. In my use case I would for example like to use something like `request.user.company` to ensure all users from the same company get the same cached version of a view.

Is it not possible to add such arguments to the per-view cache instead of defining it in the template?

Comment: You're right, it's surprising that the view decorator doesn't have this option. Consider [filing a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/) about it.